# Rerendering Handlebars template upon data change

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I have a template that shows a button based on some boolean in a JSON-object. There are two different buttons it can show.

The code for compiling the template:

```
source   = $('#some-template').html(); // Get the HTML source of the template
template = Handlebars.compile(source); // Compile it
$('#some-div-container').html(template(someJsonObject));
```

Let's say the object looks like this:

```
someJsonObject = { 
    smeBooleanValue : false, 
    someOtherValue : 5 
};
```

And the template looks like this:

```
<div id="some-div-container">
    <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="myGreatMethodForDoingThings()">
        {{#if smeBooleanValue}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" aria-hidden="true"></span> Do something
        {{else}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span> Do something else{{/if}}
        </button>
    </script>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the boolean value in `someJsonObject` changes, the view isn't updated. I thought that this would happen automatically (as it does with Handlebars in Meteor), but it seems I'm wrong?

In that case: How is it done? I can have a method for rerendering the template, which can be called in a setter for the value. The problem is that it seems that a method with the line `$('#some-div-container').html(template(someJsonObject));` doesn't do the trick.

I'm clearly missing something here. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Precompilation can be used to resolve this, check this post: [A Beginner’s Guide to Handlebars](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-beginners-guide-to-handlebars/) at the end, the **Precompilation** section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars does not handle data binding to update on value changes. You may use a framework like [ember](http://emberjs.com/) which comes with two-way data binding.

A vanilla way to perform re-rendering upon data change is using [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe):

```
Object.observe(someJsonObject, function() { template(someJsonObject); });
```

Comment: Ah, it was my experience with Meteor that confused me then. Thank you!  `Object.observe(someJsonObject, function() {  
    $('#some-container').html(template(someJsonObject));
});` did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Esso keep in mind that Object.observe is not yet supported in all browsers (http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-observe). You may want to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/jdarling/Object.observe) for unsupported browsers.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it